# Convergent Sequences involving functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $f: (M,d) -> (N,p)$ be a function and suppose that {${f(Xn)}$} is a convergent sequence, whenever $Xn -> a$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $a$

My thinking is that since Xn converges to some number a, then f(Xn) converges to some number, which would imply it is continuous at a

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know that if $x_n\to a$ and $y_n\to a$ then $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_n)$ converge to the same number?

Comment: Are you using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity? How does it follow from this "Sequential" continuity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $f$ is **not** continuous at $a$. Then $f\left(a\right)$
has a neighbourhood $N$ such that $f^{-1}\left(N\right)$ is **not**
a neighbourhood of $a$. This allows you to construct a sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)$
converging to $a$ and with $x_{n}\notin f^{-1}\left(N\right)$ for
each $n$. Consequently $f\left(x_{n}\right)$ will **not** converge to
$f\left(a\right)$.

Comment: and therefore by contradiction, f is continuous at a?

Comment: Yes. instead of $p\Rightarrow q$ this is a proof of $\text{not }q\Rightarrow\text{not }p$ wich is the same statement.